# Bootstrap datetimepicker not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am using [this](http://goo.gl/rRo8A) bootstrap-datetimepicker, but it's not working as it should

my pages includes are in turn

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
<link href="{{MEDIA_URL}}css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
```

no 404 all files are downloaded when page is rendered

On my page i have

```
<label for="id_date">Date:</label>
<input class="datetimepicker" id="id_date" name="date" type="text" value="2013-11-06 13:49:11.458000">

<script>
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker(
        {format:'yy:mm:dd - hh:mm',
         todayHighlight: true}
    );
</script>
```

but when i press on my datetimepicker i don't get the black arrows to navigate from year to year or month to month etc, and the date starts from 1900, while on the documents it is stated that default initialtDate is now

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I found what is causing the problem. When the calendar widget is added on my webpage it uses icon-arrow-xxxx where xxxx is left or right. But bootstrap3.0 uses glyphicon-arrow.xxxx. I cant seem to know how it decides to use older bootstrap version...

Answer (score 1):

I just came over the same problem and reoslved it by just changing the css. Just set the z-index for the timepicker element on higher side.